# Can somebody please explain this quote by Seneca in plain words?

Tags: meaning, quotes, philosophy

> It is not because things are difficult that we do not dare; it is
> because we do not dare that they are difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know the actual meaning of his saying and it's somewhat tricky for people who are not good at English.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote is from Epistulae Morales, 104.26.

In this passage, he is exhorting Lucilius (and his readers) to be able to bear any hardship and have no fear of anything, even death. Some might think this task impossible, but he brings up how figures like Socrates were able to do exactly that.

So why would people see this task as completely unachievable? It's because they think that they *themselves* can't achieve this, and they "reckon that whatever they can't do must be impossible" (my translation). But they're lying to themselves: in actuality, "even they can do these things--they just don't want to."

The problem is that most people just assume they can't do such things, when in fact they've never even tried. He asks: "Have these things ever failed someone who tried? Don't these things seem easier to everyone while doing them?"

Then we get to your quote (my translation): "It's not that we don't dare to do these things because they're so difficult. It's that they're so difficult because we don't dare to do them."

In other words: tasks like (say) not fearing death can actually be easy if you make a serious effort. But if (like most people) you don't even try, then they'll be forever out of your reach.